# Is the Implication $a<b\wedge a \geq 5 \rightarrow 5<b$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this a true implication?

If $a<b$ and $a \geq 5$ than $5<b$?

Comment: No.  $7>3$ and $7\ge5$ but $5\not\lt3$

Comment: $a=6$, $b=4$...

Comment: My father is older than me and my father is older than forty. Am I older than forty?

Comment: if $a>b$ and $b\ge5$ then $5<a$

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry. I edited the question right now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(Changed answer after question changed.)

$a\ge5$ means $a=5$ or $a\gt 5$.

If $b>a$ and $a=5$ then $b>5$.

If $b>a$ and $a>5$ then $b>5$.

So if $b>a$ and $a\ge5$ then $b>5$.

Comment: Sry,  it should be $a<b$

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean $b<5$ ? Then, it is true.

Author has edited now the question:
what you mean is $a\in[5,\infty)$ and $b>a$. Thus $b \in${$x:b>5 and b>a$}

Comment: what about $a=7, b=6$?

Comment: Sry, it should be a<b